# Blocking a mouse pointer movement on a key press in Windows 10

Tags: windows, pointers, locking, mouse, hardware

Unusual issue here.

Is there a way to block/prevent a mouse pointer movement on a certain key press in Windows 10? Whatever that comes to your mind?

I tried some third-party soft, macros and settings already, I didn't manage to solve it though. My purpose differs a bit from the solutions that I have found.

Purpose: when in a 3D software and moved the mouse maximum to the left, but I still want to move it further to the left, I need to take it physically over the table and put it on the right. I would like to be able to simply lock the pointer/cursor movement with some key, so that I could simply move the mouse right without picking it up over the table.

Cheers in advance,
Sergiusz

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to share a solution! I wrote an autohotkey script that does it perfectly for me, in my example I'm using a right control to block mouse movements until the key is released.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
*RControl::
    BlockInput, MouseMove
    state := true
    While state
    {
        state := GetKeyState("RControl", "P")
    }
    BlockInput, MouseMoveOff
    Return
```